# TypeError: Cannot read property 'libelle' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Error:
TypeError:Cannot read proprety 'libelle of undefined file:

this searche.html

```
import { Component,OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router,NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";
import observable = require("data/observable");
import { VoitureService } from "../../voiture/voiture.service";


@Component({
selector: "searche",
moduleId:module.id,
templateUrl: './searche.html',
providers: [VoitureService]

})
export class SearcheComponent {
    public constructor(private router:Router,private postsService:VoitureService) { 
}
voitures: voiture[];
clients:voiture;
req:string='1';
DT:Date;
idClient:number=0;
refClient:string="";
libelleClient:string;


ngOnInit(){
    this.postsService. getPosts(this.req)
    .subscribe(results => this.voitures=results );
        }

    public clicked(IDV:string,LDV:string,RDV:string){
    this.postsService. getClient(IDV)
    .subscribe(results => this.clients=results );
    this.libelleClient=this.clients.libelle;
    this.refClient=this.clients.ref;
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams:{
            libClient: this.libelleClient,
            refclient : this.refClient,

        }
    }
        this.router.navigate(["page1"], navigationExtras);
}
}


interface voiture{
id:number;
libelle:string;
ref:string;
}
```

this searche.html

```
<stackLayout  class="searcheview">
<stackLayout>

    <SearchBar class="input"  hint="MAchine" ></SearchBar>
        <ListView [items]="voitures" >
            <ng-template let-voiture="item">
                <StackLayout   rows="auto, auto"  columns="*, auto" class="list-group-item"  (tap)="clicked(voiture.id,voiture.libelle,voiture.ref)">
                    <Label   text="{{ voiture.id }}" row="0" col="0"></Label> 
                    <Label   text="{{ voiture.libelle }}" row="0" col="0"></Label> 
                    <label text="{{ voiture.ref }} " row="1" col="0"></label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
</stackLayout>
</stackLayout>
```

when i call function clicked()  im getting the error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'libelle' of undefined
please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: put  `this.libelleClient=this.clients.libelle;` in the `subscribe` callback

Comment: @echonax That SO question (and answer) comes to very good use ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 oh stop it youu :P thanks for the encouragement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory - **this.clients** is undefined at the moment you are referencing it. This is because you are subscribed to an asynchronous call and you should do your assigning operation inside **subsribe**. Possible reason for your error is because the code snippet is not formatted properly, which prevents the easy reading of your code scopes. As a recommendation use the proper indent and avoid using the short syntax for callbacks and fallbacks.

e.g.

```
public clicked(IDV: string, LDV: string, RDV: string) {
    this.postsService.getClient(IDV)
        .subscribe(results => {
            this.clients = results;

            this.libelleClient = this.clients.libelle;
            this.refClient = this.clients.ref;

            let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
                queryParams: {
                    libClient: this.libelleClient,
                    refclient: this.refClient
                }
            }
        });
}
```